# What's the comma (,) doing in the middle of Python list slicing?

Tags: python, list

What's that slicing doing here-

```
data = np.loadtxt(input_file, delimiter=',')
X, y = data[:, :-1], data[:, -1]
```

I know that -1 inverts the list and colon is start and stop signals.But what's the `comma (,)` doing in the middle?

Comment: Let's clear one misunderstanding: that is not a Python list! It is a Python object which supports `[]` (`__getitem__`) operator, but it is not a list!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NumPy supports multiple dimensions.  In your case that's a 2D slice: the part before the comma slices the first dimension, and after the comma slices the second dimension.  This implies the data is 2D or greater, and indeed `loadtxt()` does produce 2D arrays.

Ref: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: `data[:][:-1]` would just be equivalent to `data[:-1]`; the first slicing operation is essentially a no-op. So I don't think it's helpful to say that you can think of `data[:, :-1]` as `data[:][:-1]` - the first takes all but the last column of a 2d array, while the second takes all but the last row of a 2d array. Maybe you meant `data[:, None][None, :-1]`, or `data[:][None, :-1]`, but that just introduces more stuff to explain :-(.

Comment: @MarkDickinson: Good point, I deleted that part of the answer.

Comment: So to be clear `data[:, :-1]` here  -1 doesn't inverse the 2D matrix but excludes the last column?

Comment: @AlmuntasirAbir: Correct, because the commas divide the slices, so the second slice is `:-1` which is everything except the last.  `[:, ::-1]` would flip the matrix.